# Jquery SQL Array Wordpress

Tags: jquery, mysql, wordpress

I am having a problem populating an Sql array in Wordpress using PHP.

I have search.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="customerAutocomplte" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="on" />
</form>

<script src="js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#customerAutocomplte').autocomplete({
    source:'suggest_name.php', 
    minLength:2
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

And Here is suggest_name.php

```
/* Attempt MySQL server connection */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "mysql", "wordpress");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 else {
  $link->set_charset('utf8');
}
/* retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends */
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); 
$a_json = array();
$a_json_row = array();
if ($data = $link->query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE first_name LIKE '%$term%' OR last_name LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY first_name , last_name")) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
        $first_name = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['first_name ']));
        $last_name = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['last_name']));
        $code = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['customer_code']));
        $a_json_row["id"] = $code;
        $a_json_row["value"] = $first_name.' '.$last_name;
        $a_json_row["label"] = $first_name.' '.$last_name;
        array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
    }
}
// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($a_json);
flush();
```

My sql table

> "persons"

has 4 columns

> "first_name" "last_name" "email" and "customer_code"

"Customer_code" is an "AI" Primary Key. My problem is that the search does not autofill or populate an array, NOTHING, the sql database contains entries, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) you either need to specify an `appendTo` selector, or the input needs to have a sibling with the `ui-front` class.

According to [the same documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source), your `source` can be either an `Array`, `String` or `Function(Object request, Function response( Object data ))`. You're using a PHP file, which is neither of those. You'll have to write a function which can send and receive information to and from the php file in order for this to work. [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is probably the best option for such a script, as it allows asynchronous communication (i.e. no need to reload the page to 'talk' to the PHP).

These two issues by themselves are more than sufficient to break your code. It's possible that I missed something else, but I'd recommend fixing these two things first.